# posenet-python causing tensorflow attribute issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying out Posenet-python from Ross Whigtman avilalable in this GitHub:

https://github.com/rwightman/posenet-python

I am using the following code to test it out on a single image:

```
model = 101
scale_factor = 1.0
notxt = 'store_true'
image_dir = './images'
output_dir = './output'

def main():

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    model_cfg, model_outputs = posenet.load_model(model, sess)
    output_stride = model_cfg['output_stride']

    if args.output_dir:
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

    filenames = [
        f.path for f in os.scandir(image_dir) if f.is_file() and f.path.endswith(('.png', '.jpg'))]

    start = time.time()
    for f in filenames:
        input_image, draw_image, output_scale = posenet.read_imgfile(
            f, scale_factor=scale_factor, output_stride=output_stride)

        heatmaps_result, offsets_result, displacement_fwd_result, displacement_bwd_result = sess.run(
            model_outputs,
            feed_dict={'image:0': input_image}
        )

        pose_scores, keypoint_scores, keypoint_coords = posenet.decode_multiple_poses(
            heatmaps_result.squeeze(axis=0),
            offsets_result.squeeze(axis=0),
            displacement_fwd_result.squeeze(axis=0),
            displacement_bwd_result.squeeze(axis=0),
            output_stride=output_stride,
            max_pose_detections=10,
            min_pose_score=0.25)

        keypoint_coords *= output_scale

        if args.output_dir:
            draw_image = posenet.draw_skel_and_kp(
                draw_image, pose_scores, keypoint_scores, keypoint_coords,
                min_pose_score=0.25, min_part_score=0.25)

            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.relpath(f, image_dir)), draw_image)

        if not notxt:
            print()
            print("Results for image: %s" % f)
            for pi in range(len(pose_scores)):
                if pose_scores[pi] == 0.:
                    break
                print('Pose #%d, score = %f' % (pi, pose_scores[pi]))
                for ki, (s, c) in enumerate(zip(keypoint_scores[pi, :], keypoint_coords[pi, :, :])):
                    print('Keypoint %s, score = %f, coord = %s' % (posenet.PART_NAMES[ki], s, c))

    print('Average FPS:', len(filenames) / (time.time() - start))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-05f825a86194> in <module>
     54 
     55 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 56     main()

<ipython-input-13-05f825a86194> in main()
      2 
      3     with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
----> 4         model_cfg, model_outputs = posenet.load_model(model, sess)
      5         output_stride = model_cfg['output_stride']
      6 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/posenet/model.py in load_model(model_id, sess,     model_dir)
     40     print('Cannot find model file %s, converting from tfjs...' % model_path)
     41     from posenet.converter.tfjs2python import convert
---> 42     convert(model_ord, model_dir, check=False)
     43     assert os.path.exists(model_path)
     44 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/posenet/converter/tfjs2python.py in  convert(model_id, model_dir, check)
    163         variables = load_variables(chkpoint)
    164 
--> 165         init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    166         with tf.Session() as sess:
    167             sess.run(init)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'
```

Can someone provide inputs on what is causing this error and how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using TensorFlow 2.0? This code was made for TensorFlow 1.12, it will not work with 2.0

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes. I am using TensorFlow 2.x version only. Is it advisable to go back to TensorFlow 1.12 just for this? or would there be any critical features missing?

Comment: You do not really have a choice, the code only works with 1.12 unless you update it to work with 2.0 manually

Comment: Tensorflow has global_variavles_initislizer. Add the this piece of code `init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()`. If you want to use Tf 2.x import `tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()`. Thanks!